# Neither $\max S$ nor $\min S$ exists for $S=(-1,1)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set $S=(-1,1)$ is bounded. However, neither $\max S$ nor $\min S$ exists.

I think I understand this question intuitively, but how do I actually prove it mathematically? I know it is bounded because I can find a number above and below the set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that $x = \max(S) \in S$. Then $x < 1$ and so $$x < \frac{1+x}{2} < 1$$ but $(1+x)/2 \in S$, giving a contradiction to the maximality of $x$. The proof for $\min(S)$ is similar.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x=\max (-1,1)$. Then $x<x+\frac{1-x}{2}\in (-1,1)$, a contradiction.

Suppose $y=\min (-1,1)$. Then $y>y-\frac{y+1}{2}\in (-1,1)$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is a bounded non empty set then the supremum and the infimum exist but the maximum and the minimun may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, for example:

$$\min S:=\{s\in S\;;\;s\le t\;\;\forall\;t\in S\}\,$$

Can you find an element *within S* that fulfills the above? No...why? Suppose there is one such element

$$s_0=\min S\implies s-(-1)=\epsilon>0$$

Now show there's an element in $\,S\,$ between $\,-1\,$ and $\,s_0\,$ ...

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to prove that $\sup S = 1$ (and $\inf S = -1$) then this follows from the fact that a set of real numbers has a maximum if and only if its supremum is a set element (and a  minimum if and only if its infimum is a set element).